# Second derivative and dimensional analysis

Tags: calculus, derivatives, dimensional-analysis

This is from Strang's Calculus book:

> When $f$ is in feet and $t$ is in seconds what are the units of $f'$ and
>   its derivative $f''?$
>
> In $$f=16t - 16t^2$$ the first $16$ is ft/sec but the second $16$ ______

I remember from physics that the second derivative is acceleration and the dimensions are $\text{ft/s}^2,$ but how do I deduce it from the formulas?

What about the second "$16$" in the formula above? Can't make a clue about it.

Answer (score 2):

Notation: we say that the units of variable $y$ are $[y]$. So it is a little-known-in-calculus-textbooks fact that the units of 
$$\left[\frac{dy}{dx}\right]=\frac{[y]}{[x]},$$
and the units of 
$$\left[\int y\,dx\right]=[y]\,[x].$$
This implies that the units of 
$$\left[\frac{df}{dt}\right]=\frac{[f]}{[t]}=\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}},$$
and
$$\left[\frac{d^2f}{dt^2}\right]=\frac{[f]}{[t]^2}=\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}^2}.$$

As for going from your formulas, the two $16$'s have hidden units associated with them to make the final units work out. The rule is that you can only add identical units. The first $16$ evidently has units of $\text{ft}/\text{s},$ so as to cancel out the s from the $t,$ and the second $16$ evidently has units of $\text{ft/s}^2,$ to cancel out the units from the $t^2.$

Answer (score 0):

When taking the first derivative $\frac{dx}{dt}$, we remark that we get a measure of time on the "denominator" of the derivative. The same goes for $\frac{d}{dt}\frac{dx}{dt}$. We get a supplementary measure of time in the "denominator", which provides an intuition as to why the dimensions of acceleration are $\frac{L}{T^2}$. The number 16 does not change the dimensions of any quantities in the function since it is a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

The units must be consistent. All the quantities that you add or subtract on the left hand side and right hand side have the same units. Since $f$ is in ft, that means that $16t$ is also in ft. and that means that the units of the first $16$, when multiplied with s, must be equal to ft, so the unit is ft/s. Similar reasoning for the second term means that the units are ft/s^2.